# MSMQ & WCF Messages not visible in private queue

Tags: wcf, msmq

There have been a few questions similar to this, and I am VERY new to MSMQ.

I have been trying to link a ServiceContract and associated DataContract to MSMQ and have set up endpoints so that the DataContact message ends up in MSMQ.

I have verified that the message is being correctly generated by the WCF service and I can also see that messages are in the Journal of the queue I am sending to, but not in the actual Queued Message area where I'd expect them.

I am not using transactions at the moment, and I have set security to none. I attach the relevant code, though my feeling is that I am missing something fundamental through ignorance of MSMQ. Any pointers would be appreciated.

**Service & Data Contracts**

```
[DataContract]
public class RegistrationMessage : IRegistrationMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public string EMailAddress { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IRegistration
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Register(RegistrationMessage message);
}
```

**app.config of the WCF host**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MetaDataBehaviour">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <netMsmqBinding>
                <binding name="msmq" 
                         deadLetterQueue="System" durable="true"
                         exactlyOnce="false" 
                         receiveContextEnabled="false" 
                         useMsmqTracing="true">
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </netMsmqBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MetaDataBehaviour" name="Client.AuthenticationService.RegistrationService">
                <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/AuthenticationQueue"
                    binding="netMsmqBinding" 
                    bindingConfiguration="msmq" name="msmq"
                    contract="Global.DomainModel.IRegistration" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/Registration/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since no-one seems to have an answer to why the messages are being consumed, I have written a workaround in the service implementation which uses the native System.Messaging classes. This is a shame because according to the documentation, one should be able to send a message to a queue without code (as long as the endpoints are described correctly).

Here is the code I have used, for anyone in this predicament.

In the host console project, I modified the App.Config endpoint by commenting out the net.msmq and adding a wsHttpBinding to make it a regular WCF service.

```
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="MetaDataBehaviour" name="Client.AuthenticationService.RegistrationService">
<!--                <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/authenticationqueue"
                          binding="netMsmqBinding" 
                          bindingConfiguration="msmq" 
                          name="msmq"
                          contract="Global.DomainModel.IRegistration" /> -->
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/Registration"
                          binding="wsHttpBinding"
                          bindingConfiguration=""
                          contract="Global.DomainModel.IRegistration" /> 
                <endpoint address="mex" 
                          binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                          name="mex" 
                          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8080/Registration/" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
```

In the service implementation, I added the following (leaving the original Console.WriteLine statements in for testing purposes:

```
    public void Register(RegistrationMessage message)
    {
        MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\authenticationqueue");
        Message msg = new Message();
        msg.ResponseQueue = queue;
        msg.Label = "AuthenticationMessage";
        msg.Body = message;
        queue.Send(msg);
        Console.WriteLine("e-mail: " + message.EMailAddress);
        Console.WriteLine("First Name: " + message.FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine("Last Name: " + message.LastName);
    }
```

This works perfectly and works as expected, hydrating the queue. Now I can write a workflow foundation service to consume it.

Thanks to John for confirming the fact that messages were, in fact, being consumed. I would give you a vote but my level is too low :)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know WCF but I can comment on the MSMQ side.

> "I have verified that the message is
>   being correctly generated by the WCF
>   service and I can also see that
>   messages are in the Journal of the
>   queue I am sending to, but not in the
>   actual Queued Message area where I'd
>   expect them."

This means that the message was delivered AND processed.
Journal messages associated with a queue are only created when the message has been delivered AND then read/received by an application.
If a message was just delivered and not read/received then there would not be a journal message created yet and the original would remain in the destination queue.
If a message was delivered but then purged/deleted, there would not be a journal message created as the original message was not read/received successfully by an application.

Cheers
John Breakwell

Comment: Thank you for that. I did suspect this, but I am still unsure as to why the message is being consumed/processed and by what! It probably has to do withe the way the service endpoints are configured, but I can't find any information on just sending (and not processing) as I want a separate process to process the messages.